# Why can I see deleted posts?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign

I only have just over 2K rep points here, yet I can see answers others have written and deleted. Is that intentional? Or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

ELL is a beta site, so the reputation level at which you earn privileges is decreased. 2k is exactly the right threshold for the new powers you're talking about :)

You can check out the modified privilege levels [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), and see what you've already earned and when you'll get more in the future!